# Python convert python-amazon-simple-product-api results to json using Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework

I am writing an API in Python Django and rest framework. I am using a python packaged called `python-amazon-simple-product-api` to access amazon advertising API. I am trying to feed the results into the rest framework and return the results as JSON Here is my code so far.

```
class AmazonProductsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request, format=None):
        products = amazon.search(Brand="Microsoft", SearchIndex="Software",
                                 ResponseGroup="Images,ItemAttributes,Accessories,Reviews,VariationSummary,Variations")
        products = list(products)
```

With this code I get the following error;

```
TypeError: Object of type 'AmazonProduct' is not JSON serializable
```

So I am trying to find a way of making the AmazonProduct object serializable or a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not JSON serializable means that your response is an object not a primitive data that can be sent over a network.

You need to write a serializer for that model. Something like this:

```
class AmazonProductSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    color = serializers.CharField()
    title = serializers.CharField()
```

and use it like this:

```
products = amazon.search(Brand="Microsoft", SearchIndex="Software", ResponseGroup="Images,ItemAttributes,Accessories,Reviews,VariationSummary,Variations")

data = AmazonProductSerializer(products, many=True).data
return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach is to use the bottlenose [ https://github.com/lionheart/bottlenose ] instead if you just want to get the amazon results as they're and convert to JSON. Here is how I have done it;

```
amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(access_key_id, secret_key, associate_tag)
class AmazonProductsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request, format=None):
        response = amazon.ItemSearch(Keywords="Kindle 3G", SearchIndex="All")
        return Response(xmltodict.parse(response)) #json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(response))
```

Now I get the entire XML document as JSON.